# Casting a String Column to 3 Digit scale in Hive Query Language

Tags: sql, hiveql, impala

I have a select statement as follows

```
SELECT t5.Name AS ProductName
, CAST (t5.salerevenue AS DECIMAL(20,3)) AS Revenue
, CASE WHEN t5.PreviousRevenue <> 0 THEN CAST(t5.PresentRevenue/t5.PreviousRevenue*100 AS STRING)
       ELSE 'NA' 
       END AS RevenueTrend
```

I want to cast the RevenueTrend as a decimal with maximum 3 point scale (20.**123**)
I have to cast it as String because `WHEN t5.PreviousRevenue <> 0` is not met I have to show it as 'NA'

I tried doing it as follows

```
CASE WHEN t5.PreviousRevenue <> 0 THEN CAST((CAST(t5.PresentRevenue/t5.PreviousRevenue*100) AS DECIMAL(20,3)) AS STRING)
     ELSE 'NA' 
     END AS RevenueTrend
```

but I am getting a syntax error.
The revenue part is projected as expected. I want the revenuetrend part also to be projected like revenue. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting first to a decimal, then to a string:

```
SELECT . . .
       (CASE WHEN t5.PreviousRevenue <> 0
             THEN CAST(CAST(t5.PresentRevenue/t5.PreviousRevenue*100 AS DECIMAL(20,3)) as string)
              ELSE 'N/A'
        END) AS RevenueTrend
```

Comment: I was so close :). it's working I will accept your answer